# Why are opinion-based questions banned?

Tags: discussion, scope, opinion-based

Can anyone on this site guarantee that their answer is 100% correct?

If not, then why are “opinion-based” questions banned from this site?

What if people are looking for a suggestion or recommendation solutions for their problems?

What is the point if people could not ask questions when they need help?

I thought anyone could ask questions and contribute back to the community by answering other people's questions (if they can). Then other experts will determine if the answer is correct or not. If you do not like the questions or are not sure how to answer, then you can skip them. The questions could be removed after a certain time without any answer or vote. Why block them in the first place?

Comment: *"What is the point if people could not ask questions when they need help?"* -- Because this is *not* primarily a help site but rather a question and answer site, where help is given but as a secondary benefit.  Through an empiric iterative process, the site has found which type of questions work well and which ones don't, and opinion-based questions simply haven't passed this test.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a group. Or a forum. Or a discussion site.  Or a help desk.  Or a bag of popcorn or what ever else you may think it is.  It is a question and answer site.

Answer (score 15):

*"What if people are looking for a suggestion or recommendation solutions for their problems?"*

That's a great question. I'd like to specifically answer that one.

- [Reddit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit)
- [Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora)
- [Discord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discord_(software))
- Any specific forum dedicated to the topic you have a question about
- colleagues
- classmates
- friends and family

Stack Overflow does not exist to replace the web (or flesh and blood human beings...). It has a very specific goal and that is to deliver that which the rest of the web has great difficulty in delivering: facts and solutions. Directly applicable facts and solutions. Facts about and solutions for programming problems when we talk about stackoverflow.com specifically. No guesses, no opinions, no discussions, just the facts. It is officially called a Q&A site, but in reality it is a knowledge base. A decently filled knowledge base at this point; its primary function is to search for existing answers, not to contribute new questions.

So as soon as you try to contribute a new question which is designed to attract everything but facts... you're either asking the wrong question or you're simply on the wrong website. Try any of the above in case of the latter. Your question may even be answered by someone who frequents Stack Overflow. It's not like we don't like giving opinions or engage in discussions; it's just that Stack Overflow is the wrong tool for the job.

---

I like analogies with the real world. It's like walking into an Italian restaurant and asking for pizza even when pizza is not on the menu. Do you find it ridiculous that you can't get what you want and demand to be served a pizza... or do you go to a place where they actually have pizza on the menu?

Comment: To your list, there is also [DEV](https://dev.to/about) (a sort of a mix between a forum and a (user) blog/"articles" (incl. tutorials) site. And with meta [tags](https://dev.to/tags), like "[Beginners](https://dev.to/t/beginners)", "[CodeNewbie](https://dev.to/t/codenewbie)", and [Discussion Threads](https://dev.to/t/discuss)...). I don't think they have had their [Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) event yet.

Comment: Though DEV is [already plagued by rampant plagiarism](https://dev.to/faisalpathan/why-to-use-map-over-object-in-js-306m) (like on Quora and [Medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_(website))). In this case, partly of "[an answer to Stack Overflow question *Map vs Object in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541940/map-vs-object-in-javascript/49164774#49164774)". The DEV user claims to be from India.

Comment: An older list of alternative sites (MSE): *[Where can I find interesting programming discussions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/)*

Answer (score 12):

> Can anyone in this group guaranty that their answer is 100% correct? If not, then Why is the “opinion-based” questions is banned from this group?

A correct answer does not equate to a good/strong opinion, just as an incorrect answer does not equate to a bad/weak opinion.

Let's take a look at the close vote text:

**Opinion-based**
This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

"This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations". Note, this part has *nothing* to do with how "good" or "useful" the question is, but rather the types of answers it will attract. I have seen many users struggle to understand this concept. That, because Stack Overflow is looking for a specific *answer*, the *question* needs to be constructed in a particular way.

To quote [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/):
"We never claimed that subjective questions were horrible abominations that should never be asked. We simply choose to forego those subjective discussions, as there were dozens upon dozens of forums which already catered to them."

---

What is this specific answer Stack Overflow is looking for?

I think the clearest indicator of the type answer that Stack Overflow is looking for is the fact that each question as a *single* accepted answer.

Let's take a hypothetical question (that will also be hypothetically answered):

**What is the best programming language?**

Expert C++ user comes by and answers:

```
C++ of course. Look at all the things you can do with it!
```

Expert python user answers:

```
Python naturally. Look at all these cool things!
```

The question is which of these is *the* answer?

In addition, now we have several users over the years who contribute:

- Is it easy to tell which language does what?
- How do we determine how "useful" the answer is to upvote or downvote it?
- Is there a larger Python or C++ community who will confidently upvote one language more than the other?
- How easy is it to tell which answers are still relevant after 5 years? Do the concepts mentioned still apply?

As a future reader coming across the question:

- Do you know which answer best applies to your situation?
- Do you know which answer is best or has there been bias leading to oddly distributed votes?

---

Let's look at a different hypothetical question:

**How do I add variables `a` and `b` in Python?**

Answer 1:

```
a + b
```

Answer 2:

```
a - -b
```

Answer 3:

```
a - b
```

Which of these is *the* answer? Answers 1 and 2 both produce the correct results but 2 has a redundant step. Answer 3 is wrong as it produces incorrect output.  While no one can "*guarantee* that their answer is 100% correct", we *can* rate and accept questions on their *merit*. We can run timing and spacial analysis on the programs and use this to determine the *correct* answer.

---

> What if people is looking for a suggestion or recommendation solutions for their problems?

> What is the point if people could not ask questions when they need help?

People absolutely can *ask* questions when they need help, but we may not be able to *answer* the question on Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow certainly can provide suggestions or recommend solutions, but only in constraints of this platform. There are many other sites which are specifically for discussion and they can be awesome resources as well.

A hammer is not the best tool for writing a letter. Choosing the correct tool for the job is super important. Asking this type of question on SO is simply the wrong tool choice.

---

> I thought anyone could ask questions and contribute back to the community by answer other people’s questions (if they can), then other experts will determine the answer is correct or not. If you do not like the questions or not sure how to answer, then you can skip them. The questions could be removed after a certain time without any answer or vote. Why blocking them at first place?

[Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) actually already does this. However, I think the closure reason has been missed. The concern with opinion based questions is not that it will *not* be answered, but rather that it *will*.

Again the above hypothetical opinion question may attract 100s of answers covering many different languages. Leading to significant clutter and confusion. We're closing the question to *prevent* the question being answered.

> other experts will determine the answer is correct or not

This is also an issue with opinion-based answers. Who is an expert on an opinion? *Every* tool has pros and cons and they cannot all be compared equally.

In the hypothetical, the number of people who are an "expert" in *all* of the 100s of answers received are few (if one exists at all). Which will likely lead to users supporting the answers they understand. Which again leads to the issues outlined above.

Comment: Today we are experts in many languages, but even then all of them have unnerving bugs, so best is out of the question

Comment: Imo "Best programming language" would fall under "Too Broad" (even if it is strongly opinion-based). There are definitely questions that could benefit in some way (e.g. balancing the good vs. bad of two solutions in a general sense), but I struggle myself to define where that line could be drawn (aside from the current one of "no opinion-based questions").

Answer (score 2):

> What if people is looking for an suggestion or recommendation solutions for their problems?

That's just not what SO is for. We're not a discussion forum, we want factual answers.

What you're looking for is a more open / less moderated forum like **shudders** Quora.

Comment: Well, at least they answer absolute beginners' first two questions: 1) Is it too late to start learning to code at age X? (X: 16 to 98. And with *zero* context.) 2) [What programming language is best to start learning first?](https://www.quora.com/What-programming-language-is-best-to-start-learning-first) (again, with *zero* context). [However](https://www.quora.com/Im-74-Am-I-too-old-to-learn-how-to-code-If-not-what-language-s-should-I-learn), [there](https://www.quora.com/Is-the-age-of-15-too-old-to-start-learning-code-If-not-where-can-I-begin-to-learn-code)

Comment: cont' - [isn't](https://www.quora.com/Is-30-really-too-old-to-start-a-career-as-a-developer) [any](https://www.quora.com/q/become-a-great-programmer/I-am-40-years-old-I-want-to-learn-programming-and-want-to-be-a-very-good-web-developer-Is-it-possible) [end](https://www.quora.com/I-am-20-year-old-and-recently-started-learning-Javascript-HTML-and-CSS-Is-it-too-late-Can-I-become-a-good-web-developer-and-get-a-good-job) [to](https://www.quora.com/I-turn-50-this-year-Am-I-too-old-to-pursue-a-career-in-computer-programming) [them](https://www.quora.com/Im-27-is-it-still-worth-it-to-learn-coding).

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I dare not click those! Yikes!

Comment: **Quora is absolute trash.**  I am almost tempted, to downvote this answer, just because it suggests any question is worth of it.  Did I mention I hate Quora?  I especially hate them because they require an account to even view answers.  **Upvote initiated since this answer gave me an opportunity to call Quora trash.**

Comment: @Security Hound: And now [they erected paywalls around old answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384396/ban-chatgpt-network-wide/385009#comment1288858_385009), hyphen site and IMDb style (sort of).

Answer (score 1):

We close questions to prevent answers. We prevent answers that are only expressing personal opinions. There's always an aspect of opinion in programming but some questions are primarily opinion-based, e.g. which programming language is the best? Such questions have no place here and they should not be answered.

In the past, we allowed such questions and it turned out that they often don't provide any value to the site. One's opinion may vary depending on one's circumstances. If it can't be supported by facts then it won't ever be a solution to the problem, which Stack Overflow answers' are meant to be, a solution to a problem.

Comment: Sometimes either a protocol is designed for something or it isn't. And that's a fact.  Like assembly language is designed to produce machine level code---that's a fact.  Suggesting that assembly language "can" produce faster execution is not an opinion.  So I think that when you look at whether or not a judgement about a programming language or an API is an opinion, the factuality can get muddled when you have to consider issues like whether or not you're looking at a virtual machine or whether you're dealing with an interpreter or a compiler.

Comment: How do you suggest to a less knowledgeable user that running interpreted code on a virtual machine is going to be inefficient?  You have a platform that is, in the end designed one way or the other and there isn't a whole lot of in between.  I don't know if you can take design specifications to be a matter of opinion.

Comment: @user1329514 - I would point them to any number of discussion forums, blogs by legends in the field, or a book written by someone with a good technical team. What I wouldn’t do I submit an answer to a SO since the question wouldn’t be a good fit.