# Why do I constantly keep getting downvoted and my questions get closed because they "need debugging details"?

Tags: discussion

I know there will be some people who will rush to say "Well, obviously your question is unclear" and my answer to them would not be very polite. That is because I have posted 4-5 questions of which only one got upvoted. This has become increasingly annoying, as I need answers fast and people just seem to project their hate and complexes on me despite the fact that I have provided the question, my faulty answer, the outcome, the expected outcome and any other comments to *further* explain the situation.

Someone please enlighten me on why this community is even more toxic than Reddit or Twitter, because it really does not promote productivity or assist anyone.

P.S. I am a beginner, so my questions are also a matter of two minutes to answer for advanced programmers...

Comment: I assume you meant [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70002014/write-a-python-program-which-reads-y-or-n-and-adds-1-until-the-number-reaches-5) ? I havent come across any other one...

Comment: This community is not designed to promote productivity or assist individual users. As explained in the [tour], our goal is to build a *knowledge base*. Low-quality questions do not contribute usefully to that goal, so such questions are downvoted, closed, and/or deleted. If you are resolutely unwilling to accept feedback regarding the clarity or completeness of your questions, , then I am not sure how we can help you.

Comment: I notice that you didn't take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), but doing so is useful because it tells you what SO actually is: "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming." A library of knowledge, not a free, personal help desk. That advanced programmers could answer them in 2 min suggests that they are likely duplicates. It has nothing to do with "hate" or "complexities", it's just content curation, when the contributions don't meet SO's standards.

Comment: Questions where the title starts with: "Write a Python program that..." are not actually *questions*; they're *assignments*, which don't fit into a Q&A model.

Comment: Content rating isn't toxic. If you see it as toxic, that isn't the community's problem; the problem is the quality of the content you have provided. Some would suggest that the "toxic" side of that is the person who posted the low quality content (which isn't the users that voted).

Comment: _“Someone please enlighten me on why this community is even more toxic than reddit or twitter, because it really does not promote productivity or assist anyone.”_ — This is not productive; so what is the purpose of this post? Looking at [your original post](//stackoverflow.com/q/70002014/4642212), the first revision essentially contained “Write a program that does X. I’ve written this code, but it doesn’t work.”. Read [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905).

Comment: Then, you’ve added a bunch of noise complaining about downvotes, stating _“I have provided all the requirements.”_. Really? So, you must have read [How to Ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which tells you to provide a [minimal reproducible example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which links to [How to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). So, what did these steps reveal and why did you choose to not include any of your research in the question?

Comment: Honestly, the question linked in the comments above reads like a *homework help* question. The community has additional expectations for such questions, and users that don't follow those can find themselves harshly downvoted. Have a read of [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/2029983)

Comment: Also SHOUTING (all caps) at users is often only going to attract downvotes. Adding that you explicitly call out downvoting, even more so. Shouting at us is just rude; you're asking for *free* help on a problem from others in the *free* time. They are under no obligation to help you, and being rude to them is not going to make them feel obligated, or even interested in putting in any effort.

Comment: @CodyGray well this is not a community for advanced users either. My question was perfectly understandable, and you know that as you did not edit anything regarding the question. It is people like you who consider beginner-level questions to be "Low-quality" and this is exactly the problem with this platform. And besides, who is to say there are no other beginners on this platform looking for help? Your argument is void in this instance and I am sorry

Comment: With respect, you clearly don't; otherwise you would not have posted this question.

Comment: @Larnu I do not understand what I am supposed to do in case I need help with homework. Do I include a specification that the question is about my homework or what?...

Comment: "*well this is not a community for advanced users either"* The majority of users you get answers from will be "advanced" users. Without those users, this community would fall to ruin where the quality of the answers is poor; and there will be no advanced users to warn others about the (fatal) flaws of said answers too.

Comment: *" I do not understand what I am supposed to do in case I need help with homework"* Have a look at the FAQ article I linked in the above comment. it explains in details the expectations. Giving us your assignment and just saying "my attempt doesn't work" doesn't meet those expectations.

Comment: My job, as a moderator, is to remove things that violate site policies, like rants and abusive language. I don't go around clarifying people's questions. I am not a Python programmer, so I couldn't tell you if your question makes sense or not. In fact, although you consider yourself a beginner, you likely know much more Python than I do. Of course, this is *not* merely a site for advanced programmers. All levels of questions are welcome here. Being a "simple" or "basic" question doesn't make it low-quality. However, being a requirement-dump does tend to have that effect.

Comment: @Larnu That is what I am saying, I read the FAQ and I still do not understand what is necessary to do. From what I picked up, I have to provide my code which I have looked at multiple times and specify what is wrong with it, both of which I did on my last question. If there is anything else, please tell me

Comment: [We believe asking questions on our site is a privilege, not a right.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/) If your contributions don't meet SO's quality standards, SO is the wrong place for them. It's not a tutoring service.

Comment: @JeanneDark there is also no other place to ask beginner questions either as far as I know. Plus, if you read Cody Gray's last comment, he does allow for "simple" or "basic" questions on this platform. Instead of lecturing me and repeating what others have said, would you mind telling me instead what I can do in order to get an answer to my question?

Comment: @SebastianSimon if you looked at my second revision of the post, I included everything else. I removed the "Doesn't work" and provided the exact issue with the program. I did not include a specific example like "ah I entered 'o', got a correct answer, then 'n' and got a wrong answer" as this was implied in the edit. And regarding the title, I had seen a similar question once, so I thought that is how I am supposed to ask. What title would you suggest for the current question, so that I can repost it properly?

Comment: @GeorgeTsakoumakis I _did_ look at your second revision. But surely the downvotes started while your first revision was visible, or else you wouldn’t have added all these complaints. What stopped you from giving a detailed description in your _first_ revision? Regarding the title (I didn’t write that comment), it’s not about the _title_. It’s about the general pattern of “do my homework for me”-like posts.

Comment: For starters, @GeorgeTsakoumakis, you don't ask about the problem you're having. You give us your assignment, and just tell us your attempt does work. *"ask the question about the code you wrote to solve your homework problem and be specific with the inputs, desired outputs, and error messages."* We don't need your assignment task, just details about the specific problem you're having.  Also *"**Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation**"*; you don't tell us what the problems with your attempts are other than they don't work.

Comment: _I do not understand what I am supposed to do in case I need help with homework_ I must be getting old, I still remember when homework was something you did without the need of crowdsourcing. Do you not have a teacher or other people in the same class  to talk to about this? Why is your first thought to outsource your thinking? _Grumble_ Kids these days _grumble_

Comment: "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming."  --such utopian goals, historically, end badly.  EVERY question???  ...and then what?  questions not allowed?  sounds very bad and very un-American to me.

Comment: I've already seen good questions get punted in my short tenure here.

Comment: @Andrew Not literally every single question, it means as many as possible. There will be no end to them because technologies are constantly being developed and then you can ask about those new things.

Comment: _very un-American_ What a strange thing to say with regard to this situation. I don't get the impression anyone was claiming that it's particularly "American", nor related to other countries

Comment: related: [When is Stack Overflow going to stop demonizing the quality-concerned users who have made the site a success?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366858/839601)

Comment: To reiterate what others have said before, this isn't a "help site" per se, and many new users of the site can become frustrated with it due to not understanding this key concept. It is a question and answer site where both questions and answer quality are *curated* by site users with the goal of creating a collection of high-quality questions and their answers. Help is often obtained, but as a useful by-product, not as a primary goal. Comments are there to give you feedback and help you create better questions, questions that we hope will be judged good enough to keep and be answered.

Comment: Here is a similar post with wild speculation about motives: *[Why is this specific question closed and doesn't it reflect poor (elitist?) community functioning?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371919/)* (it will probably be auto-deleted soon)

Comment: Not an exact match in terms of the subject of the question, but here is an inventory of [some of the alternatives to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409384/why-are-opinion-based-questions-banned/409391#409391).

Answer (score 27):

If you need an answer fast then posting on Stack Overflow is not the right thing to do. We are not a help desk. We are trying to ["build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming"](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

**Nobody is downvoting you!** Votes are a content rating system. We rate the usefulness of each post for future readers. If your posts are getting consistently downvoted then maybe you should spend more time before you post to analyse how useful your new topic will be for the community.

Voting is not toxic. On the contrary, it is the nice thing to do for future readers. We let them know what is not useful and they don't need to waste time reading it.

> I am a beginner, so my questions are also a matter of 2 minutes to answer for advanced programmers...

Then I highly doubt you should post these questions on Stack Overflow. Simple questions like this have been asked multiple times and when you post it again, it will just be closed as a duplicate. You need to come up with a brand new topic. Something for which you can't find an answer on Stack Overflow yet.

Make sure you read the [Expected Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) page.

Comment: This is the opposite of helpful. I might be a beginner, which is exactly why I expect some form of help from advanced users. I don't think anyone would feel much obliged from such a trivial question, but unfortunately, I cannot answer it on my own, and I require assistance.

Comment: @GeorgeTsakoumakis As long as this topic hasn't been covered yet on Stack Overflow then feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: @GeorgeTsakoumakis _" I might be a beginner, which is exactly why I expect some form of help from advanced users."_ That mindset is far from adequate here. As others have explained here, this site is not a helpdesk, and contributors work as volunteers. As a consequence, no one is really entitled to receiving help when asking a question.

Answer (score 14):

Well for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69904207/write-a-python-program-that-reads-a-number-of-values-and-calculates-their-averag) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69726806/how-can-i-separate-these-inputs-and-still-make-them-a-float)

1. What values are you using to test it?
2. What output are you getting, what output do you expect?
3. Are there any values that do work?

Those "debugging details" are missing. I note that in one of your other questions you do [include such information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69902498/write-a-python-program-that-reads-a-positive-integer-n-and-finds-the-average-of)

Also how is it you're unable to progress. Are you stepping through the code in a debugger? Why is that unrevealing as to how to progress?

I also see you've accepted answers on three of your questions so you are getting useful answers. Downvoting isn't "hate" it's a measure of quality. We're also not here to "answer questions fast", we're all volunteers here.

Take the time to look at other questions on this site that are upvoted and see how they differ in structure from your questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is exactly what I was hoping to hear, and by that I mean a useful answer which will help me post clearer questions in the future. However, many people in the comments are mad at me for "posting homework" because I am a beginner/intermediate user. Unfortunately, I do not meet their expectations, but there is nothing that I can do about them. Could you point me in the right directions regarding that?

Comment: @GeorgeTsakoumakis: Maybe this is helpful for you: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs)

Comment: Some people don't like homework questions because they feel you're not learning what you should be if you get them answered for you. You can help avoid this by breaking down the question into the specific piece you're stuck on rather than presenting the whole thing.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that [code/input/output provided as images might as well not exist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Transcribing them to ``code`` formatted text is important to help us answer questions.

Comment: @RobertLongson also, there are folks like me who dislike h/w because [these make site less worthy for us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367319/839601), "I want Stack Overflow to keep helping people like me - those who get their answers here after dumping their question into google search box... I don't want my search results polluted with useless solutions to homework dumps..."