# Add a profile section to save common comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request

For a lot of new user questions, I copy / paste the same comments.

For instance, in the [Bash tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash), when a question is about syntax errors, I often have to ask the OP to paste their code in [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and to use the `set -x` flag in their script to check if there is not a trivial problem that could be fixed with those tools. Then, they can edit the question with more details.

Couldn't there be a section in your profile to save often used comments? At the moment, I have a text document with those comments, and copy/paste them when necessary.

Comment: Opinions on "canned comments" are mixed; with some being actively against them. The above isnt a good example, in my opinion, as such a comment would likely be better with details specific for the question.

Comment: Comments like these really aren't helpful; that's part of the reason we don't have a place that encourages it. You should probably re-consider posting them. A better way to express this concern is to cast a close vote for the applicable reason. If there's no applicable reason, then there's no problem with the question, and no code is required to be shown. Not all questions are seeking debugging help.

Comment: If you want to have it now, you can save it on your About me, hidden with the HTML comment `<!-- -->` ...

Comment: As an alternative: https://gist.github.com/ ? But a text document seems ok.

Comment: @CodyGray the problem with close votes is that more often than not, the question gets closed before the asker can edit their question to make it valid. I'm also aware that some questions don't need code, but I'm speciffically asking about the case when the question is below SO standards, but can be salvaged if the user edits the relevant information

Comment: "*the question gets closed before the asker can edit their question to make it valid*" That's exactly how it should work. What use would it be to close the question if it is already improved by OP? We only close questions that are unanswerable and are awaiting an edit from the OP.

Comment: The problem, which I do agree with, is that providing an inbuilt solution for canned comments *promotes* their use. I'm not necessarily against canned comments (I do use them myself) but I use them as a template and alter or expand on them when needed; this is a nuance than many users probably won't adopt if there was an inbuilt feature, making the comments at best noise.

Comment: @Dharman yeah, but on the other hand, people are way quicker to close than to reopen. I agree it should work like that if the system was perfect, but the reality is that salvageable good questions get ignored

Comment: Then a problem is that questions don't get reopened when they should. Closing isn't the issue here. You are barking up the wrong tree

Comment: *"people are way quicker to close than to reopen"* I see no evidence of this; the processes are perfectly parallel. The primary difference is that the vast majority of new questions that get asked are in need of closure, whereas the vast majority of closed questions are *not* in need of re-opening, even after edits.

Comment: I feel like there is a missing feature here. If you would just be able to save canned comments in your user CP, you'd still be needing to copy/paste them. Not a whole lot changes from your text file situation, besides having the canned comments available to you on any computer. Is that really all you wanted, or is the missing feature that you would want to be able to select your comment from or around the comment box itself?

Comment: @Gimby yeah, the quick select was what I had in mind, but even a way to sync your favorite template comments with your profile would allow you to access them on multiple devices

Comment: Just FYI, there is a venerable userscript called [Auto Review Comments](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments) that does just that, and much more. We are also [working on](https://github.com/userscripters/SE-AutoReviewComments) modernizing ita little since it's been unmaintained for a while.

Comment: The same information is in the [Bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info), section *"Before asking about problematic code"*, *"5. Check the example for common problems"*. Perhaps the close reason should contain a reference to the tag wiki for those tags where it is appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you vote to close the question as "Needs Debugging Details" instead?  From what you describe, the OPs you encounter enough to be bothered to comment on their questions have this common issue in which they don't really ask a *complete* question, so you have to poke and prod them to get them to get on board.

At least with question closure, [you're sending a consistent message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417184/1079354).  With comments you're making it seem like it's kinda OK to post an incomplete question when [we *expect* that the question is 95% ready to go](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/413125/1079354) before they hit submit.

Comment: But how would they know what to do? Do they see more than *"Needs details or clarity - This question should include more details and clarify the problem."*. Aren't they left in the dark?

Comment: @PeterMortensen:  No?  They get a link to the Help Center which [does explain a few things about what could be missing *in general*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), so I wouldn't count that as being in the dark.  If there is a shortcoming with *this*, then file a [tag:bug] and highlight the issue being that more guidance needs to be available in close messages.  Instead of us trying to fix the bug in a way that isn't ever going to be sustainable, let's actually get this to the forefront of the company and make *them* responsible for fixing it.