# Are there any Stack Exchange sites where recommendations, best practices or industry standards questions can be asked?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Stack Overflow is focused on Q&A style questions. Questions that seek recommendations, best practices or industry standards are discouraged because they may generate discussion and are seen as opinion-based.

What other Stack Exchange websites are there where such questions can be asked? I have a particular interest in Python in case there are technology specific sites.

Comment: I can't think of any that i'd suggest, i usually leave these kinds of questions to private communities I'm part of, as if i don't/can't reasonably trust the person giving me their recommendations.. what good is the recommendation?

Comment: The main site doesn't allow external resource recommendations, what makes you think it's ok to ask here on MSO?

Comment: It was suggested on StackOverflow that I ask here.

Comment: I have edited the question accordingly to ask for Stack sites

Comment: https://softwareeengineering.stackexchange.com might worth a try, although they are too strongly bound by their own hardly comprehensible rules, so the risk will be huge.

Comment: https://software.codidact.com is more lenient than the SE sites in this regard - for example program design questions are on-topic. Though questions still have to be specific there.

Comment: @peterh: Recommendations are off-topic on [softwareengineering.se] as well. In fact, SE.SE even uses the exact same pre-defined close vote as [so]. Software recommendations *can* be asked on [softwarerecs.se], unsurprisingly, and hardware recommendations on [hardwarerecs.se]. Questions about best practices *can* be asked on SE.SE, *IFF* the querent provides a precise, unambiguous, objectively measurable definition of "best" … otherwise, they are just asking for opinions, since what is "best" is a matter of opinion.

Comment: [Another list of alternatives](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409384/why-are-opinion-based-questions-banned/409391#409391) (here on MSO)

Comment: "industry standards" - that one puzzles me. What industry, exactly? Software engineering pretty much cuts through every industry in existence and what you do in A does not apply to B.

Comment: @JörgWMittag It is bad. Programming is much more than the lexical knowledge of various languages and frameworks. Entirely missing this topic on cloudy reasons is a bad practice.

Comment: If you accept an answer, that prevents it from the automatic deletion due to low scores. It does not prevent the deletion by moderator/review votes.

Comment: @Lundin: It also seems to lack a userbase... At least it no longer looks like a SO clone now that SO has been redesigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no SE site where you can ask all of them. But you can ask probably all of them on at least one.

1. Software recommendations can be asked on the https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com
2. Best practice might be on-topic on the https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com , but beware, it is very restrictive,
3. "Industry standard" is a very broad thing. The steepness of the screw threads is an industry standard (ontopic on the https://engineering.stackexchange.com ).  But the details of the POSIX standard belong to the https://unix.stackexchange.com . Specify more the standard and find the optimal site for that.
4. Lexical knowledge about various languages/frameworks, debugging help, "why it does not work", belong to the Stack Overflow. Beware, SO is a lesser friendly one among the SE sites.

Typically, it is a good idea to break down a broad question, about multiple site topics. Think on that you are an investigator and you are interrogating people in various [communities](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-questions). Then you put the fragments together, and integrate it into what you can find from other sources.

Have also a feedback loop:

1. You search and learn
2. You ask what you could not find/learn
3. You think on the answers
4. GOTO 1

Maintaining multiple questions at once might be too resource intensive, particularly if you need extra effort to defend them (on lesser friendly sites, its probability is higher). It is better to focus only to one question at once.

Comment: Another trick: if your question is threatened by the "too broad" closure reason, then create an example and ask only from the example. So it won't be too broad any more. The "off-topic" closure reason can be avoided by asking it on the correct site, or breaking the question into multiple topics and asking it all on different sites. The "unclear" closure reason can be handled by listening the comments and doing what they suggest [typically extending the question with extra info], even if they don't look very useful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. In the end, it seemed like the question I had in mind would not be accepted at any Stack site. I found a specific place to ask it and get an answer: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/discussions/3051

Comment: @mcarans Yeah, this is why I the github could create its own Q&A in a space dominated by the SO. Problem is that it is imho a very good question and it is a shame that there is no way to ask it in the SE network, but most of the github questions I find by google is... well... garbage. Most of the askers have a problem to create a round sentence on any language. The strength of the SO is that that pile of crap what is the github Q&A in general, is filtered here out mercilessly. Disadvantage is that such diamonds like yours, are with this filtering lost.

Answer (score -11):

According to a comment by Dan Bron on this answer, the short answer is no. There isn't any Stack Exchange website for such questions.

I found [an article](https://medium.com/@techloop.io/tired-of-stack-overflow-and-github-here-are-the-alternatives-c970d64a0bd3) that lists some alternatives including some other Stack sites, but I do not know if the other Stack sites mentioned would allow such questions:

"**[The Code Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Project)**

*The Code Project* is a similar site to Stack Overflow with developer queries as well as a ‘quick answers’ section for questions that get asked on a regular basis. However, Code Project differs in the fact that it also has an extensive range of articles as well as a discussion area. It is said that a lot of the content on The Code Project focuses on Windows programming.

**Code Ranch**

Code Ranch is another similar forum site that is a great place to go for Java developers as the site is predominantly focused on this languages. That’s not to say there aren’t resources available for other languages and there is also forum threads on wider subjects such as recommended books and a careers section.

**Other Stack Exchange sites**

For an alternative to Stack Overflow it is also worth checking out some of the other Stack Exchange sites such as *[Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour)* or *[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)*.

Although not specifically for programmers, the programming languages sections of **Quora** can also be a good place to go if you want to ask something you’re afraid to ask on Stack Exchange!"

Comment: The question (now) asks specifically about Stack websites. The majority of this answer deals in non-Stack sites. You’ll want to update it. Note that Programmers (now called Software Engineering) doesn’t arrive questions of recommendations, best practices, or industry standards. The original site was launched as an experiment to see if that was workable in Stack’s QA format, and the experiment’s results determined the answer was *no*. So the charter/mandate of the site was changed, and the name along with it. The shower answer to the OP is “nowhere on Stack Exchange”.

Comment: @DanBron Your commentary is spot-on.  I remember back when some of these items were acceptable, and there were a few stellar examples of great utility that did fit into "recommendations, best practices, and industry standards."  However there were far too many duplicates, and many were far too specific to be reused.  That's not counting the noise from vanguards of a technology.  Finally, upvoted answers became wrong over time, and there was no real way to age them into obsolescence without a complete rework of voting rules, which would break the social contracts inherit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Huh, coderanch is imho very bad to mention. It is probably the nightmare of the java googlers of the last decades. I think mentioning coderanch might be the main reason of the downs. (I did not vote this answer.)