# Is there a place on Stack Exchange to ask a question about the Google Play Console?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am having a problem with the Google Play Developer Console (where you upload apps to the Google App Store) and a problem trying to use the Help form to ask about the problem. Can I turn to Stack Exchange for help and if so where?

My question would be something like:

> The Play Store seems to be demanding a link to a "Privacy Policy" even
> though I have said the app does not collect personal data and is not
> aimed at children. When I go to fill out the Help form it wants my
> Developer account ID and when I enter my e-mail address it says:
>
> ```
> "! Please try reformatting."
> ```
>
> with no clue as to what that means. It's a perfectly valid and normal e-mail address. I tried several addresses including a gmail address and all give the same error. Is that a technical problem? I have tried every
> variation I can think of, and tried a Web search.

Comment: It would help if you could be more specific about the issue but it looks like questions about the Developer Console are specifically off topic over on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Aside that, what BSMP said -- some questions, notably the type that falls under customer support, are off-topic everywhere in the network. Some questions may be on-topic over on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-console), but I don't use webapps.SE, and have no idea what goes over there, so use common sense before you ask there

Comment: Well, I didn't provide details because that would be *asking* the question here, right? I wanted to ask *where* to ask the question. <g>

But sure. The Play Store seems to be demanding a link to a "Privacy Policy" even though I have said the app does not collect personal data and is not aimed at children. When I go to fill out the Help form it wants my Developer account ID and when I enter it it says "! Please try reformatting." with no clue as to what that means. I  have tried every variation I can think of, and tried a Web search.

Comment: @Charles: On Meta site voting has somehow special meaning. You could read about it e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus).

Comment: [A list of alternative sites here on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409384/why-are-opinion-based-questions-banned/409391#409391). [A longer, but less credible list](https://www.quora.com/What-are-other-question-asking-websites-like-Quora). [An older list on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/). None of them are necessarily fit for this particular case, but it can not be ruled out either.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on *"a problem trying to use the Help form to ask about the problem"*, preferably by editing your question? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now.). E.g., what Help form? Here on Stack Exchange? Somewhere else? What was the nature of this problem? Presumably not a technical one. The SE one [requires JavaScript to be allowed from google.com and gstatic.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#comment1218384_71208)

Comment: cont' - It may be important if using something like [NoScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I am sorry -- I don't know what you mean about editing without Edit:. The statement of the problem above is pretty complete except for yes, the Help form in question is the Google Console Help form. I put it my e-mail address and it will not accept it with the sole error of "! Please try reformatting." It's a perfectly valid and normal e-mail address. I tried several addresses including a gmail address and all give the same error. Is that a technical problem?

Answer (score -4):

It appears that MSDN Developer Forums consider Google Play Store questions to be on-topic.

Comment: MSDN Developer Forums considers everything to be on-topic. They have great recipes on how to make pickled onions ...

Comment: I will have to check them out.