# Question bans aren't a good way to make users improve their questions. Can you remove the 'question ban?'

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, post-ban, banning

People like me-they don't ask good questions. They never will until they have asked a ton of questions. I think you should remove the question bans permanently for all users. You could add some sort of tagging on the question to warn people it's not a great question. But it's not a great way for users to improve if they can only ask a question twice a year. Can you think about removing this ban, and replacing it with something more friendly (e.g. tagging posts with 'bad-question')?

Comment: _"You could add some sort of tagging on the question to warn people it's not a great question."_ we already do, it's called _**downvoting**_.

Comment: ideally, the question ban isn't meant to make people improve. It's meant to *stop people who have shown that they can't*. I think the former bit is what needs to be improved, aka, helping people learn that they need to improve *before* they get stuck in a hole. A lot of messaging already occurs on this front, but people are so accustomed now days to just ignoring popups that they're often ineffective.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how removing the question ban helps. What we *don't want* is poor quality questions. Removing the ban is going to add more poor quality questions. What exactly is the benefit here?

Comment: "People like me-they don't ask good questions." That is *not* a good way to start such a request.

Comment: In other words we need more effective methods of getting users attention. Roadblocks, if you will, to asking when the user is new or when their posts are generally not being well received. hopefully whatever new system they're currently cooking up for new askers helps address this

Comment: Snarking aside, what would be the motivating factor to change behaviour without a ban? For "not-banned people" to learn how to ask good questions, they would still need to receive regular feedback and answers. Where is the incentive to change, then?

Comment: If you know you don't ask good questions then why keep on asking them? Nobody is forcing you to contribute to Stack Overflow. There are plenty of other things you can do with your free time. Please remember that Stack Overflow is not some free help desk. You are not entitled to contribute here, you have the privilege of doing so and if you knowingly post bad questions we want the system to ban you.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, then you could only do ***downvoting***, not question bans.

Comment: Downvoting alone wouldn't stop users who only post problematic content.

Comment: @DaCuteRaccoon "*Well, then you could only do downvoting, not question bans.*" you still haven't explained how removing the question ban *helps* the site.

Comment: [The Saga of the Evil Bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_bit).

Comment: Interesting fun fact: Once you learn how to ask good questions you'll find you ask a lot fewer questions. A good question-asking process finds solutions.

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0, contributing to the [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans): [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/71354820) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/71289137)

Comment: Please read this if you can't ask new questions: **[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583)**

Comment: The desperation may be relieved by reviewing [this list of alternative sites here on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/409391). [A longer, but less credible list](https://www.quora.com/What-are-other-question-asking-websites-like-Quora). [An older list on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13198/).

Comment: Re *"They never will until they have asked a ton of questions"*: That is like writing without ever having read a single word. [To write](https://www.autocrit.com/blog/reading-make-better-writer/) [well, you](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/14189/can-i-be-a-good-writer-without-reading-a-lot) [need to read a lot](https://goinswriter.com/good-writers-read-2/). I think the same applies here - ***[lurk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lurker)***. *"Lurking allows users to learn the conventions of an online community before they participate,"*

Comment: I think that this question is spot on, but why stop at removing question bans? I think that they should remove training and licensing requirements for commercial pilots, since these roadblocks only prevent people like me, who will never be good pilots, from fulfilling our dreams of flying large airplanes full of passengers.

Comment: @user4581301 I think that is the root of the problem: people who can write good questions don't need to post them on SO, people who can't write need to ask a lot of questions and SO is the place...  And SO needs all those piles of questions to find pearls (also after 10 years it feels more like search for diamonds with mountains of dirt rather than original pearls in sand). Q-ban is just a compromise between "we do need all questions out there" and "chance that this account produce a pearl is -100%"...

Comment: *"Question bans aren't a good way to make users improve their questions"* - They exist to protect the repository from further damage; and it's a very effective measure indeed. Whether someone acts on the ban is a happy side effect, not the main goal.

Comment: You may want to keep an eye on company efforts to improve the question asking experience, like this post requesting [stories about user’s first question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416428/improving-the-first-time-asker-experience-what-was-asking-your-first-question).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Okay, let's go over your points

> People like me-they don't ask good questions. They never will until they have asked a ton of questions.

Even after you re-read and applied all advice in [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), [Guidance after being downvoted](https://idownvotedbecau.se/) and the rest of the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)?

> I think you should remove the question bans permanently for all users.

No, Yahoo! Answers tried that. They are history. The Stack Exchange network strives for quality content and that means that the entry barrier is a tad higher than anywhere else on the internet.

> You could add some sort of tagging on the question to warn people it's not a great question.

That is exactly why we have voting and closing here. That warns all visitors that the content they are reading has issues.

> But it's not a great way for users to improve if they can only ask a question twice a year.

It is plenty of time to read-up on all the guidance we have, suggest edits, vote and flag on other posts, and learn how the SE search engine works.

> Can you think about removing this ban, and replacing it with something more friendly (e.g. tagging posts with 'bad-question')?

No, tagging like that is what we call a "meta tag". We used to have one for "homework". That tag got quickly added to almost everyone's ignore list. We're not here to do homework.

I do think we can do more to make it clear up front what goes into a great question. But we exist because everywhere else on the internet everything goes, literally. We have checks and balances. We try to collect useful content that is findable by generations to come. That comes at the cost of having a quality entry barrier for posting here. That might have an impact here and now for you but in the grand scheme of things Stack Overflow is pretty successful due to the quality content we curate here. I would rather optimize for the many consumers but I take that from your point of view that is not a helpful position.

Answer (score 13):

> People like me-they don't ask good questions. They never will until they have asked a ton of questions.

If you habitually ask bad questions, you should not be permitted to post them. We certainly don't want to give you the opportunity to ask tons of low-quality questions in the hope that you'll eventually improve. Not to sound harsh, but either improve or don't; we're not here to hand-hold you into writing good questions.

Stack Overflow is intended to be a repository of high-quality Q&A, not just a generic help site. Questions are expected to help all future readers, not just you.

> But it's not a great way for users to improve if they can only ask a question twice a year.

They've been given multiple warnings that their questions are bad before they reach the question ban.

If they want to improve, they can work on editing their existing questions.

> Can you think about removing this ban, and replacing it with something more friendly (e.g. tagging posts with 'bad-question')?

No, that's not what tags are for - this is a classic meta tag. Tags should describe the question's topic, not general attributes of the question. Also, if the system knows that a question is bad, it should prevent it from being posted at all, not just tag it as a bad question. In principle at least, we don't want *any* bad questions on the site, just good questions. (Obviously, that's not practically achievable, but we still don't want to allow known bad questions to be posted).