# Was this question about pngquant alternatives and image optimization in PHP correctly closed?

Tags: support, specific-question, asking-questions, closed-questions

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71639339/need-image-optimizer-for-php-pngquant-alternative-that-does-not-need-shell) about a PHP alternative to pngquant

> I used to use pngquant to optimize images uploaded to our website,
> works fantastic. But our new server has shell_execute and similar
> functions disabled for security reasons. So no running command line
> tools. Is there any alternative way to optimize images from PHP only,
> perhaps with GD or something?

A few very helpful people did post comments that I was grateful for, but almost immediately the posting got 2 down votes, then suddenly it was closed siting "This question needs details or clarity".

Were the downvotes and closing warranted?

Comment: I'd have voted for seeking recommendations but lacks details is also acceptable. Maybe even too broad. I find it quite unfriendly that you accuse people of "elitism" when the question doesn't quite fit under the guidelines.

Comment: Help me understand why it is off topic for SO? I was looking for a way to accomplish something in PHP? Not appropriate on SO?

Comment: @ihatzi no, you most definitely did not ask for opinions. Your post was very directly accusatory. You don't get to take umbrage behind "innocent question" when it was not at all innocent. -

Comment: But I thought I did, problem is I couldn't run pngquant because shell was disabled. Also, I was getting great feedback until it got closed. Why is this bad for the site?

Comment: Perhaps it would be more constructive to help me understand how I could have posed the original question properly.

Comment: We're trying to explain how the site works in our different ways hoping that you'll understand one of these explanations. How to pose the question 1. Try to implement  image optimisation in PHP. 2 tell us where specifically you're stuck implementing whatever optimisation algorithm you've chosen.

Comment: There is [a Stack Exchange site for software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour)—but check their policies before posting. You can also review [this list of alternative sites here on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/409391). [A longer, but less credible list](https://www.quora.com/What-are-other-question-asking-websites-like-Quora). [An older list on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13198/).

Comment: I note you don't have the `informed` badge yet. This tells us that you have not completed the [tour], a quickie presentation that exposes you to the absolute minimum usage information about Stack Overflow. If you have not taken the tour when it was offered when you signed up, it casts doubts on whether or not you read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) from the How to Ask? Help pages.

Comment: Also watch out for the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect). Often asking Why was my question poorly received will draw additional eyes to the question and if it really isn't up to snuff, those extra eyes will add to the downvoting. Make sure any issues raised in the close reason and comments, if any, have been addressed..

Answer (score 19):

As posted, the question is a request for off-site resources: you are asking for "an alternative to pngquant" to use within PHP.

Requests for off-site resources are effectively off-topic.

You *could* reformulate the question as: *"How to optimize an image with PHP?"*, qualify it a bit with some constraints, and it *might* work.

I personally feel the question would not nearly focused enough, not being too far away from *"How to optimize an image with a computer?"*, but I know some users would deem it fine and on-topic.

However, it would be a severely under-researched question, since just a teensy bit of searching for those keywords would yield **a lot** of information about the topic.

All in all, I believe the question was correctly closed, and even if it could be somehow salvaged into a nominally on-topic question, without a lot of research (which would likely answer the question, and simply leave you with much more specific and actionable issues to solve), it would still be a very poor question likely to attract downvotes.

Comment: I don't agree with you, but thanks for a great response (trully).

Comment: The reason I disagree, is because I am actually looking for a PHP alternative to pngquant, not something off the shelf but actual PHP code that accomplishes what pngquant does.

Comment: I do feel that was a pretty specific question, because pngquant does something very specific

Comment: I think that would be also covered by my answer here (e.g. converting the question into a "how to do X")

Comment: "How to reimplement X application/library" is inherently too broad. And underspecified, since users need to check an external source (the library/application/utility you want to reimplement) to see what exactly you want to implement.

Comment: Would asking the question this way have been better....

Is there a function in PHP that is equivalent to pngquant...

pseudocode
   $img = gdQuant($img);

Comment: Instead of focusing on a tool, focus on a task. During your research, think _"What does tool X accomplish? I'll research that"_.  You'll then get a better idea of what questions to ask (if any).