# What is the best Stack Exchange site to discuss general artificial intelligence?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, site-crossover

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [I want to make an AI. How do I combine words to create context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71758296/i-want-to-make-an-ai-how-do-i-combine-words-to-create-context)

I figured that AI would be mostly discussed on Stack Overflow, however it seems that this is not the case. One user commented that I should look for another site to post my question on. Which site?

Comment: ai.stackexchange.no

Comment: https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It may fall under recommendation questions. There is [a list of alternative sites here on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/409391). [A longer, but less credible list](https://www.quora.com/What-are-other-question-asking-websites-like-Quora). [An older list on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13198/).

Answer (score 16):

Don't think there's any site that can really accommodate you without going radically against the nature of Stack Exchange itself.

The problem with your question is, fundamentally, you're asking to do something *huge*.  I mean, *huge* huge.  Making an AI is a complex undertaking that has had trillions of dollars and hundreds of thousands of person-hours behind it in the past.

Natural language processing - which is what you allude to here - is also a very complex subject and a very complex thing to just "do".  Thankfully there are some libraries and services out there which help do that very thing (operative word: help).

If you could come to the network with some information about something *specific* you wanted to do with some specific library or service you were leveraging, then you'd *might* have a smoother time.

But your current question in its current state?  Wouldn't fit on the network.