# Where should I go to complain about overzealous moderators?

Tags: discussion

I had a problem.  I spelled out in some detail and posted the question, with code and the tests that were done.

Some moderators wanted more details, so I added it.  Finally, they deleted the question.

Others (based on the comments) also had the same issue.  ***Why would they delete a question*** that had valid answers (even if only in the comments)?  This just means that someone else will post the same message since they can't find the one I posted.

There appears to be no way to "Argue my case" with anyone who can intelligently respond with anything appropriate.  Or if there is, how do I do it?

Comment: It is a frustrating and imperfect system at times, that's for sure.

Comment: You would go to [meta] - please note that this was likely *not* a moderator, but community members with [particular curation privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) that assess questions through either the review queues or by encountering them during browsing. Edit - now that it's migrated, please edit your question (here) to include a link to the deleted question and the specific concern you have, so that it can be looked at.

Comment: *"with anyone who can intelligently respond with anything appropriate"* language like this can easily reflect poorly on your question. Try to avoid talking down on users or insulting their intelligence, it's not constructive and will tarnish people's opinion of you, and the rest of the question's content. I would suggest [edit]ing such language out.

Comment: Note that you can find deleted questions in your profile. Providing the actual question (as a link and/or screenshot) could help change this meta Q&A from a rather hostile rant to an actually specific question.

Comment: As a note, the question was deleted by the system, not by a moderator. For more information [see this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

Comment: If there were valid answers in the comments, they could/should have been posted as answers - you can even [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Upvoted answers *in the form of answers* could have very well prevented automated question cleanup from deleting a question that otherwise had no answers.

Comment: Until now, none of your questions had any interactions by any of the SO mods. You have a couple of deleted questions, but they were deleted by the system.

Comment: No idea which question is being talked about, so here's all of them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176515/excel-via-interop-returns-date-not-text-value (closed, deleted by the system), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71709632/how-to-create-a-version-point-in-tfs-for-a-product-release (not closed, deleted by the system), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002283/trying-to-find-gui-report-writer-for-c-sharp-wpf-2019-application (closed, deleted by the system), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60328257/ (closed, deleted by the system)

Comment: As the complaint from the OP is that "moderators" (read curators) are overzealous, I feel I shall, on this occasion, explain my close vote reason: this is because in the question's current state it is little more than a rant, and the OP has failed to respond to any comments or requests for clarification (such as what question(s)  they are referring to, what moderators (read moderators), or change their tone of their question). As such, I don't feel that the OP is looking for discussion, as they would have responded by now, and so it *is* just a rant and so should be closed.

Comment: @Larnu to be fair, based on the OP's location and timezone, it's plausible that they could have started their workday and cannot address it until their hours end. I'll keep an eye out here to vote to reopen if the appropriate edits are made.

Comment: Ahhhhh! The robots are stealing our posts! Oh. Wait. Community's [not a robot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=badges).

Comment: [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused their privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-their-privileges). This technically answers the question though it doesn't actually apply in this case.

Comment: If you ever find a place to complain about moderators, you should definitely charge for entry. You will make a killing!

Comment: Re *"Are any tools, best practices, etc. I can try that will help me identify if a given object (VM in this case) has some reference to it that prevents it from properly being released from memory?"* (60328257): There is site *[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour)* - *"Good software recommendation requests have two components: a purpose (a task to accomplish, a user story) and some objective requirements (a minimum set of features)."*

Comment: For general recommendations (e.g., 71709632), there is also [this list of alternative sites here on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/409391). [A longer, but less credible list](https://www.quora.com/What-are-other-question-asking-websites-like-Quora). [An older list on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13198/).

Comment: Well, the OP is yet to return still, @nanofarad , so I would suggest that they didn't plan  to at this stage. If they do return, they do still need to do significant [edit]s to their question though.

Answer (score 19):

As [noted by @Catija](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418426/where-to-go-to-complain-about-overzealous-moderators#comment912947_418426), it was automatically deleted as it [met the criteria for getting Roomba'd](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). You still have options though, covered next.

As @Zoe [provided links to your deleted questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418426/where-to-go-to-complain-about-overzealous-moderators#comment912954_418426), one of them was closed as being opinion based. You never got a response asking why it was opinion-based before the post was deleted, so I'll direct you to this phrasing in the question body:

> Are any tools, best practices, etc. I can try....

This is a very open ended type of question and is considered off topic for Stack Overflow. These types of questions invite not only opinionated answers, but spam as well. Reworking your question to be about a *specific* tool, API, etc. you are having trouble with may be grounds for undeletion or re-opening.

Although since the question already centers around asking for recommendations, a new, more concise question may be the best and swiftest course of action.

In fact, going through that list of questions, most of them are seeking recommendations or ask an open ended question (yes, even [this one where you insist you are not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63002283/584676)). In general **you should avoid asking open ended questions**.

---

[This question is a different story, however](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72176515/584676), and there are different problems with it:

- When asked for a code sample, you became argumentative in the comments about "not needing to provide a code sample", especially once you said the known fix didn't work for you.

  The candidate answerers were ***telling you they needed to see your work to help you***. If we can't answer your question because of missing information, it is *going* to eventually be closed as **Needing details or clarity**.
- In the comments it comes to light that this issue is not limited to programmatic entries, but manual ones as well. Arguably, that would make the question off topic for Stack Overflow in the first place as it is about normal software functions, not a programming problem.

---

As for:

> There appears to be no way to "Argue my case" with anyone who can intelligently respond with anything appropriate. Or if there is, how do I do it?

You have two options available to you:

1. Address the concerns made by commenters as to missing details and other information required to solve your problem.

   - Subsequent edits after closure or deletion get added to a review queue for reopening.
2. You can ask on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) at any time about the question and argue your case.

   - Note that ***nobody is required*** to give your posts any attention when asked about on here, although ***if you are respectful*** your case will get the due attention it deserves.